# What is yourinfo.allrequestsallowed.net?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my apache instillation, I keep seeing the following line in my access logs:

```
"POST http://yourinfo.allrequestsallowed.net/ HTTP/1.1" 200
```

It's really freaking me out because this site is not being hosted on my server (I checked the IP just to be 100% sure). I added a "Deny all" line since the site is still in development, and now the HTTP 200 response changed to 403, like the domain is being hosted on my server.

I'm incredibly confused and scared. Does anybody know what's going on? Can I Deny all to this domain that's apparently pointing to my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Jon Lin pointed me in the right direction, I figured it out.

After disabling mod_proxy and enabling mod_security, I added the following to my virtual host configuration:

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecRule REQUEST_LINE "://" drop,phase:1
```

And then restarted apache. It quits the connection and returns any amount of data, which uses less resources and bandwidth during Brute Force and DDOS attacks.

Also, it shows as an HTTP 404 Response in the access logs.

**EDIT**: I updated the rule to drop all types or proxies (https,https,ftp). I don't know how many protocols can be used this way, but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check to make sure you don't have `ProxyRequests On` set anywhere where it's not supposed to. Typically a request like that is for a forward proxy and the troubling bit is that you returned a `200` response which could indicate that the request was successfully proxied.

Take a look at this [wiki page about Proxy abuse](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse).

> **My server is properly configured not to proxy, so why is Apache returning a 200 (Success) status code?**
>
> That status code indicates that Apache successfully sent a response to the client, but not necessarily that the response was retrieved from the foreign website.
>
> RFC2616 section 5.1.2 mandates that Apache must accept requests with absolute URLs in the request-URI, even for non-proxy requests. This means that even when proxying is turned off, Apache will accept requests that look like proxy requests. But instead of retrieving the content from the foreign site, Apache will serve the content at the corresponding location on your website. Since the hostname probably doesn't match a name for your site, Apache will look for the content on your default host.

But it's probably worthwhile to check that you aren't proxying. Otherwise, it's not really that big of a deal.

Comment: ProxyRequests wasn't declared as on, but it wasn't declared as off either. I added a proxyRequests Off to the virtual host, and it's still returning 200s. Since I have limited bandwidth for the time being, I'd like to make this stop entirely. I'll do more research on it tomorrow though.

Comment: I had some spare time and got it figured out, Thanks for giving me a starting point.